# How to do a search view in my case? android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code to retrieve data from cloud firestore. Now I need to add a search view to the activity so it is easier to find the user in the activity, but I don't know how to do it, or where to add it. If anyone can assist me with that.

Here is my code to retrieve the data.

Users.java:

```
package com.example.how;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public class Users extends AppCompatActivity {


private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference UsersRef = db.collection("Users");
private UsersAdapter adapter;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    setUpRecyclerView();
}
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    Query query = UsersRef;
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UsersModel> options = new 
FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UsersModel>()
            .setQuery(query, UsersModel.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new UsersAdapter(options);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FireStoreList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

}
```

Here is activity_users.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Users">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/FireStoreList"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="686dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is userdetails.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:padding="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFName"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="121dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDOB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLName"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtemail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDOB"
        android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtemail"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="First Name: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Last Name: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="Date of Birth: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="Email: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Phone Number:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="User ID: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution with minimal hassle: Just add a single line EditText to your Activity Layout with a submit Button and then just start another Activity on button clicked action to display search results.
Add the elements in the xml layout and then connect them in the Java code.